# Opening an Eclipse project in another Eclipse instance on another computer

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I've created a Java project with two packages using Eclipse on my desktop computer. Each package has a number of files, including some JUnit tests. The project root directory is located in my Dropbox folder, and I'm now trying to open this project from my Laptop, without access to my desktop.

I've managed to get 'Import' the project using

`File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace`

but the imported project only partially resembles the one I had on my desktop.

On my desktop my structure was

```
MarsRover
L src
| L org.ChrisWilson.MarsRover
|   L File1.java
|   L File2.java
|   L File3.java
|
L tests
  L org.ChrisWilson.MarsRoverTests
    L Test1.java
    L Test2.java
    L Test3.java
```

So, I have the project called `MarsRover` at the top, two directories called `src` and `tests` below that. Each directory contains one package, called `org.ChrisWilson.MarsRover` and `org.ChrisWilson.MarsRoverTests` respectfully, and each of these packages contains the source and test files.

My imported project looks like this:

```
MarsRover
L bin
| L org
|   L ChrisWilson
|     L MarsRover
|       L File1.class
|       L File2.class
|       L File3.class
|     L MarsRoverTests
|       L Test1.class
|       L Test2.clas
|       L Test3.class
L src
| L org
|   L ChrisWilson
|     L MarsRover
|       L File1.java
|       L File2.java
|       L File3.java
|
L tests
  L org
    L ChrisWilson
      L MarsRoverTests
        L Test1.java
        L Test2.java
        L Test3.java
```

Both my packages have been lost and everything is now just a directory. I am no longer able to run either my project or the tests.

What I want is to be able to open my project in Eclipse running on different computers and have the first project structure. I'm new to both Eclipse and Java, and would welcome any advice on how to make working with these two tools on different computers as easy as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a risk of "conflicted files". Wenn you have your project open on desktop and notebook at the same time, they make changes to the projectconfig which could be not mergeable by dropbox. so its better to move to git ore something similiar (perhaps at bitbucket.org) and ignore the .metdata-dir of eclipse (every client has his own project config)

Comment: I agree. Not sure how you could share projects with DropBox.

Answer (score 0):

I have had very good experiences with creating Maven projects (where the pom.xml describes the layout etc).

The simplest for now is most likely to create new maven projects and move your existing code into that.

You will need an Eclipse distribution with "m2e" (or download "m2e" from the Eclipse marketplace) and then you can copy the projects to a new computer and use Import -> Existing maven projects there.

Answer (score 0):

It just seems you're looking at the project structure in the Navigator view (which displays files and folders) rather than looking at it in the Package Explorer view (which displays source folders and packages).

Use Window - Show View... - Package Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there's no `Package Explorer` option there. I used the search bar and it brought up nothing.

Comment: There should be one. Try pressing Alt-Shift-Q, then P.

Comment: Nothing happens, and the menu the appears with the list of views doesn't mention a 'Package Explorer', nor do any of the views listed have `Alt+Shift+P P` shortcut. It should be noted that the only options I have under the `File -> New` menu are `Project`, `File` and `Folder`. There are no Java-specific option, such as Java classes, JUnit tests or packages. Could the import have gone wrong somehow?

Comment: You probably installed a version of Eclipse which isn't made for Java development. Reinstall a fresh copy of the right version of Eclipse.